# Get records with last child record

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `Sites` model which hasMany `Posts`.

I would like to know whats the most efficient eloquent query to return all Site records along with the 1 (most recent) Post record.

I have tried using this in my Sites modal but it returns all Posts which is not what I want.

```
public function lastPost()
{
      return $this->hasMany('App\Post')->last();
}
```

Another issue I am having is trying to print a single column in my view.
`{{ $site->lastPack->name }}` returns

> $name undefined property

... despite this being a valid column in my Post model.

Comment: why you just dont `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()` ? (or use updated_at)  then `{{ $site->lastPost()->name }}` or you can return it from the controller or use View composers

Answer (score 1):

Change Your `lastPost` relationship to `hasOne` like so:

```
public function lastPost()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post')->latest('id');
}
```

Comment: This works when return just a JSON view in the following structure: post > last_post, however when I try to access this in my blade template like `$site->last_post->name` I get `Trying to get property of non-object` error

Comment: Long story short: use `$site->lastPost->name` structure and it will work just fine. When laravel converts model object to array, it takes all relationships and convert names to snake_case. So thats why You able to access `last_post` in Your JSON return. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2556